# Example of first-order quantum phase transitions between two gapped phases with unique ground state in local 1d spin chain without extra symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, phase-transition, spin-chains

I'm trying to better understand first-order phase transitions in local, 1d quantum systems, particularly spin chains. I realized that I don't have a strong understanding of what's possible and impossible for first-order transitions.

I'm familiar with the example of the transverse field Ising model in the ferromagnetic phase, and then adding a longitudinal field $h_z$. If we vary $h_z$, we'll see a first-order phase transition between two gapped phases with unique ground states (dressed versions of the all up and all down states), with the ground states effectively crossing at $h_z=0$. However, to me this is a very pathological example -- it relies on explicit symmetry breaking caused by $h_z$; $h_z=0$ and $h_z \neq 0$ are models with different symmetries.

I want to see if there are other examples that behave similarly, but that do not rely on such explicit symmetry breaking. Does there exist a local spin chain featuring a first-order phase transition between two gapped phases with non-degenerate ground states, with the additional constraint that there are no extra symmetries at the phase transition relative to the abutting phases?